# Users with Limited access to selected files in Sharepoint cannot open Documents folder

Tags: sharepoint, office365, document

In sharepoint I have assigned Read permissions to specific files & assigned them to limited users.

Within documents I'm expecting these users to just see these files.

Currently, within Site Contents they can  see the Documents folder(which they couldn't before), but opening the folder does not return any files/folders.

I've performed a check permission on a user & it states that Limited Access has been assigned directly.

I'm fairly new to the admin side of sharepoint so I'm not sure what I need further to see the expected contents of the Documents folder.

Can anybody advise what I need to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online, you only need to share the files to the users who you only want to give limited access. Without giving permission in the folder/library level, SharePoint only provide limited-access for them. Enabling them to have a way to find the files. The process is like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c). And I used to explain the meaning of limited access [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/358999/how-to-get-rid-of-limited-access-on-sharepoint-onl.html).

For now I would like to know you actual process on sharing the file. And you can check the access on the files which users need to have permission. We have an option called "manage access". Select the file and use this option to check the existing access on these files.

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have created the access for both a user and a group.  This has been tested in 2 ways - Firstly by selecting the file; manage access & then adding permissions via the plus sign.  Secondly, select the file again and then via share.  Users can see the file via the shared link but they cannot navigate through Site Contents, Documents.